# sdkmanager specifying revision of packages

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

We are installing the android sdk and all the packages required to build our app in a docker container.

However there's a detail that has been bugging me regarding versions.

Take a look at the all the sdk manager available packages below (the list has been shortened)

```
$ sdkmanager --channel=3 --list
Installed packages:
  Path                              | Version      | Description                       | Location
  -------                           | -------      | -------                           | -------
  ...
  build-tools;25.0.1                | 25.0.1       | Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.1    | build-tools/25.0.1/
  build-tools;25.0.2                | 25.0.2       | Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.2    | build-tools/25.0.2/
  build-tools;25.0.3                | 25.0.3       | Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.3    | build-tools/25.0.3/
  build-tools;26.0.0                | 26.0.0       | Android SDK Build-Tools 26        | build-tools/26.0.0/
  ...
  platform-tools                    | 26.0.0       | Android SDK Platform-Tools        | platform-tools/
  platforms;android-17              | 3            | Android SDK Platform 17, rev 3    | platforms/android-17/
  platforms;android-18              | 3            | Android SDK Platform 18, rev 3    | platforms/android-18/
  platforms;android-19              | 4            | Android SDK Platform 19, rev 4    | platforms/android-19/
  platforms;android-20              | 2            | Android SDK Platform 20, rev 2    | platforms/android-20/
  platforms;android-21              | 2            | Android SDK Platform 21, rev 2    | platforms/android-21/
  platforms;android-22              | 2            | Android SDK Platform 22, rev 2    | platforms/android-22/
  platforms;android-23              | 3            | Android SDK Platform 23, rev 3    | platforms/android-23/
  platforms;android-24              | 2            | Android SDK Platform 24, rev 2    | platforms/android-24/
  platforms;android-25              | 3            | Android SDK Platform 25           | platforms/android-25/
  platforms;android-26              | 1            | Android SDK Platform 26           | platforms/android-26/
```

Some packages include the version on the `Path` making it obvious that two different image builds will have the exact same package. If you would like to update it, then you have to change the install command from `build-tools;25.0.3` to `build-tools;26.0.0` for example.

However, there are packages that do not have the version in the `Path`. 
Let say we have a build including `platforms;android-25`, the current docker image might install the `Version 3` (latest at the moment), but next time we build the image there might be a `Version 4` available, meaning that with the same dependency name we end up with different installed packages. We will not know about this, and it might cause build issues as they are not deterministic.

While this is an basic example, things get more complicated with other dependencies such as the `extras;android;m2repository` or `extras;google;m2repository`, in which a revision could mean that there are new version of the packages included (firebase for example).

In other words, is there any way to specify what `Version` of the package we want to install so we always end up with the same dependencies installed ?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone with strict package version requirements should probably run their own local repo anyway. If you don't want to host all the binary package files - you could just host your own custom `repository.xml` with package versions you require and still use google's repo for the package files.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot. The only way is to find a direct download link for the version you need (and back it up!)

For example, the current revision for platforms-16 is 5, and I found earlier revisions here http://venomvendor.blogspot.com/2012/07/download-android-41-jelly-bean-api-16.html